# Override methods with different generic types

Tags: java, generics

I have following classes:

```
public class A extends Exception {
}

public class B extends Email {

}
```

My goal is to implement some strategy that would be able to work with both those classes like below:

For instance:

```
public enum Strategy {
    ACTION_1 {

        @Override
        public void handleAction(Class<? extends Exception > parameterThatShouldAcceptOnlyA) {
            throw parameterThatShouldAcceptOnlyA;
        }
    },
    ACTION_2 {

        @Override
        public void handleAction(Class<? extends Email > parameterThatShouldAcceptOnlyB) {
            parameterThatShouldAcceptOnlyB.send();
        }
    };

    public abstract void handleAction(Class<?> parameterThatShouldAcceptBoth);
}
```

This is not compiled through incorrect generic in overriden methods.

Could you please suggest how it would be possible to make this workable?

Comment: Are you planning on calling `ACTION_1.handleAction(...)`, or `someDynamicStrategy.handleAction(...)`?

Comment: Clearly the problem is that you're using `Class<T>` type. This type does not represents an object of type `T`, but meta information associated to a Java class. The other problem, is that you're try to generify an `enum`, which is not possible. Try to define a `Strategy<T>` interface instead.

Answer (score 2):

You better step back here. Your idea simply violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).

Basically you want to **restrict** a subclass in what can be passed in as argument to a method.

That breaks the whole idea that subclasses can be used in place of their superclass. Because now, all of a sudden, the code that wants to call that method has to **check** the type of the object it is calling on - to ensure to **not** call the method with "invalid" parameters.

In other words: take this compiler error as a *symptom*. Even when you somehow work around the specific issue; as said - you better step back and rethink your whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: It is neither possible to throw a `Class` instance nor to invoke other methods than provided by class `Class` so at first you need to change your parameter type. This also let you remove the wildcards.

You can define the super class by a generic. Unfortunatelly enums do not support generics. But you can create a generic interface like

```
interface Handler<T> {
    void handleAction(T t);
}
```

and implement your handler like

```
class EmailHandler implements Handler<Email> {
    void handleAction(Email email) {
        email.send();
    }

class ExceptionHandler implements Handler<Exception> {
    void handleAction(Exception e) {
        // Exception is a checked exception
        // so we cannot throw it without 'throws' declaration
        // but we cannt add 'throws Exception'
        if (e instanceof RuntimeException)
            throw (RuntimeException) e;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("wrapped", e);
    }
```

Comment: Using a `Class<T>` object as method parameter is not useful, if you need to invoke methods of type `T` on it ;)

Comment: OP's parameter is `Class<?>` and I don't know what is done with it. But you're right: in most cases T is needed.

Comment: Please, correct your answer and specify that the using of `Class<T>` is worthless.